# FAB with material components look square

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I'm using a FAB in my layout but looks weird. I try with invalidate restar cache but nothing happens.

This is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

This is how its looks in the layout editor:

[image]

This is how its looks in the emulator

[image]

Any idea about how to solve it? I read other post but nothing works.

UPDATE:

Material version: 1.2.0

Theme: Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar

Comment: Thats how it looks on the device or just the layout editor?

Comment: Which version of material components are you using and which app theme?

Comment: @tyczj this is how it look in the layout editor

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @Coeus then I would not worry about it, check it on a device/emulator, layout editor should not be considered 100% accurate all the time because it might not be able to render everything

Comment: @tyczj Looks weird the FAB in the emulator XD